# Web crawler that charts stock ticker data using matplotlib

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, matplotlib

I've built a web crawler using the `BeautifulSoup` library that pulls stock ticker data from CSV files on Yahoo finance, and charts the data using `matplotlib`.  I'm wondering if there are any ways to improve the code I've written, because there are some parts that I think could be a lot better.

```
import urllib.request
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def chartStocks(*tickers):

    # Run loop for each ticker passed in as an argument
    for ticker in tickers:

        # Convert URL into text for parsing
        url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=" + str(ticker) + "+Historical+Prices"
        sourceCode = requests.get(url)
        plainText = sourceCode.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plainText, "html.parser")

        # Find all links on the page
        for link in soup.findAll('a'):
            href = link.get('href')
            link = []
            for c in href[:48]:
                link.append(c)
            link = ''.join(link)

            # Find the URL for the stock ticker CSV file and convert the data to text
            if link == "http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=":
                csv_url = href
                res = urllib.request.urlopen(csv_url)
                csv = res.read()
                csv_str = str(csv)

                # Parse the CSV to create a list of data points
                point = []
                points = []
                curDay = 0
                day = []
                commas = 0               
                lines = csv_str.split("\\n")
                lineOne = True
                for line in lines:
                    commas = 0
                    if lineOne == True:
                        lineOne = False
                    else:
                        for c in line:
                            if c == ",":
                                commas += 1
                            if commas == 4:
                                point.append(c)
                            elif commas == 5:
                                for x in point:
                                    if x == ",":
                                        point.remove(x)
                                point = ''.join(point)
                                point = float(point)
                                points.append(point)
                                day.append(curDay)
                                curDay += 1
                                point = []
                                commas = 0
                points = list(reversed(points))

                # Plot the data
                plt.plot(day,points)
                plt.ylabel(ticker)
                plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Composing small functions

`chartStocks` would be more readable if you split it into a handful of smaller functions, roughly like this:

```
def chartStocks(*tickers):
    for ticker in tickers:
        page = getTickerPage(ticker)
        csv_url = findCSVUrl(page)
        csv = getCSV(csv_url)
        day, points = parseCSV(csv)
        plot_data(ticker, day, points)

        # Or, if you're allergic to temporary variables:
        day, points = parseCSV(getCSV(findCSVUrl(getTickerPage(ticker))))
```

This approach lets you clearly see the "pipeline" your data is passing through, and lets you test and reuse smaller pieces individually.

Arguably it would be even cleaner to define `def chartStock(ticker)` to handle the case of one ticker, so that `chartStocks` is just

```
def chartStocks(*tickers):
    for ticker in tickers:
        chartStock(ticker)
```

The only thing to be careful of here is to make sure to design your functions to handle errors properly -- either check that each return value is not `None` before calling the next function, or allow them to take `None` as a parameter and just return nothing in that case.

### str.startswith

This:

```
# Find all links on the page
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    href = link.get('href')
    link = []
    for c in href[:48]:
        link.append(c)
    link = ''.join(link)

    # Find the URL for the stock ticker CSV file and convert the data to text
    if link == "http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=":
        # ...
```

could be simplified with `str.startswith`:

```
def findCSVUrl(soupPage):
    CSV_URL_PREFIX = 'http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s='
    for link in soupPage.findAll('a'):
        href = link.get('href', '')
        if href.startswith(CSV_URL_PREFIX):
            return href
```

I've also provided a not-found value of `''` so that if `link` has no `href`, `startswith` won't get called on `None`.

### Skipping first row

Instead of using a `lineOne` flag when looping over `lines`:

```
lineOne = True
for line in lines:
    if lineOne == True:
        lineOne = False
    else:
         # continue parsing line...
```

you can just start from *after* the first row with a slice:

```
for line in lines[1:]:
    # ... continue parsing line
```

### CSV parsing

Python has a built-in CSV parsing module that could simplify a lot of your parsing. It would do the splitting-by-commas for you and return either a list or dict of fields for each row, depending on what you ask for. You would end up with roughly this:

```
def parseCSV(csv_text):
    csv_rows = csv.reader(csv_text.split('\n'))
    days = []
    points = []

    for day, row in enumerate(csv_rows):
        close = float(row[4])
        days.append(day)
        points.append(close)

    return days, points
```

where the `enumerate` function would give you the same zero-based days list as you currently have.

Actually, since it seems like `days` will just be the list `[0 .. len(points)]`, you could skip the `enumerate` and simply define `days` after you've parsed all the points, and toss in a list comprehension if you'd like for good measure:

```
def parseCSV(csv_text):
    csv_rows = csv.reader(csv_text.split('\n'))

    points = [float(row[4]) for row in csv_rows]
    days = list(range(len(points)))

    return days, points
```